# Is it possible to have a pull down menu to have an item selected in its list show if database already has information in it?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, mysqli

Version 4:

I have taken away the pull down menu for now, I just want the info to be posting correctly.

As it shows with the first line fab1 shows #2, in the second line it shows 1, --None-- instead of 2, Andy Khal. If anyone can figure out why, it be appreciated. I've done about as much as I can to figure this out and I'm lost.

```
<?php
// Connect to the database.
require_once('tb/connectvars.php');
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("MySQL failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Create the SQL query
$testbed = "SELECT * FROM testbed";
$user = "SELECT * FROM user";


// Execute the SQL query and store the result set in
// the $result variable.
$testbed = mysqli_query($dbc, $testbed) or die("Failed to execute query on tesbed table: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
$user = mysqli_query($dbc, $user) or die("Failed to execute query on user table: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

// Read the results.
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($testbed);
if(!$row)
{
  echo 'Query failed<br />';
}
else
{
    echo "Query for Testbed Fabricator is : " . $row["fab1"] . "<br />";
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user);
if(!$row)
{
  echo 'Query for Testbed Fabricator failed<br />';
}
else
{
    echo "Query for User ID # is : " . $row["userid"], $row["user"] . "<br />";
}


// Free the result set.
mysqli_free_result($testbed);
mysqli_free_result($user);



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You can specify the selected value with the `selected` keyword as a html attribute.

`<option value="Username" selected>Username</option>`

That makes this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $user = $row['user'];

    echo '<option value="' . $user . '"';
    if($user is known)
    {
         echo ' selected';
    }
    echo '>' . $user . '</option>\n';
}
```

### Update

In this snipped `$choosen` is the selected user's name.

```
echo'<div id="fab1">';
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
$mysqli->select_db('user');
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
echo "<select name='fab1'>\n";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo '<option value="' . $row['user'] . '"';
    if($row['user'] == $choosen)
    {
         echo ' selected';
    }
    echo '>' . $row['user'] . '</option>\n';
}
echo "</select>\n";
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: I hate to ask, but how would that work in the script I originally posted?

Comment: Replace your while loop with mine. Then check whether the user is already choosen and place this as a condition to my if construct.

Comment: Ok, I did what you suggested, now I get an error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: I can't help you with the error explaination only. Paste the source code and type down the error line. Have you replaced `($user is known)
` with your own routine?

Comment: Yes, but let me tweak the code a little and I'll edit the original post. What is confusing me is your option tag, because no where is there a "username", and the actually $user is known, that is key for me it seems but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Sorry... it seems i can't get it working, copy and pasting the way I have it now won't matter since I know I don't have it written right.

Comment: http://kaboomlabs.com/testbed/box.php  Here is the working code, otherwise I am lost in how to get yours to work with mine.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Sorry. Maybe you need to send the user's selection via GET or POST...

Comment: Where does `$row['fab1']` comes from?

Comment: Updated answer. How do you get the selected user's name?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, was on the road. The selected username is in the table testbed under row $fab1.

Comment: no... here is the link with the script you provided in practice.

http://kaboomlabs.com/testbed/box.php?id=1

Comment: Do you have any idea on why this isn't working? This should be showing Andy Kahl as a selection, not --None--...

Comment: i cant see any php language there.

Comment: Dang it... I made a mistake, try again.. I forgot it would do that.

Comment: You have to use GET or POST to save the users selection. This is your working file: http://www.file-upload.net/download-4055321/php_get_selectoptions.zip.html

Comment: Ok, I hate to say it, I am somewhat following what you have done, but you put a lot in there that honestly won't work with what I have. userlist doesn't exist, The other issue is that user names, isn't the whole purpose of the table is to not have to add those lines in there? I'm just curious... because if it's easier to just write in the code into the script instead of pulling data down, I will but I'd rather not because this needs to work with other parts as well that are too long to add into the script and make it viable.

Comment: After the script was ready I commented out some lines for testing (e.g. the database connection lines, because I don't have your database.) Then I added some new to provide test data. You should learn the php basics if you don't understand the file. Exspecially the GET method.

Comment: Well you had my database originally... remember when the link pushed out the data? Well that data was the database in question. That being said, your data still won't help because it's pulling the information from a script, and not an SQL database list.

Comment: Ok, these are my last two comments here. Learn programming and you will understand it, I am sure. I can't tell you more than above: In my file are lines commented out. They are lines for database connection and so on. Remove the `//` in front of them or the `/* ... */` around them and delete the "testing lines" instead (wich provide testing data instead of mysql data). That shouln't be a problem.

Comment: In detail: remove the `/*` in line 5 and the `*/` in line 8. Remove the `//` from line 23 and 26. Remove line 27 and 24. (in this order) I tested it and it works well. Please accept my answer and get further reading on fundamental principles of programming. Bye.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7040/discussion-between-sharethis-and-matt-ridge)

Comment: I am in chat, and will remain there, I may not answer immediately because I am AFK, so respond and I will see your response, we may as well do some chat tag.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: I responded as you left, in any case, here is the link with your script: http://kaboomlabs.com/testbed/box.php?id=1